# Android Debugging technique for Program Crash ---Source Not Found

Tags: android, debugging

it says Source not found, but what source its talking about? It didn't specified. And if it does where would I find those source files?   Before it hit this source not found exactly is its problem?  I mean, all the variables are initialized and got values.   What cause the crash?    I am kind still kind of new in debugging in Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there are several causes of this but the ultimate solution is to wrap your calling code in a try catch block so that you can output the actual error to logcat. Check out the following for examples of how to set this up.

http://moazzam-khan.com/blog/?tag=android-source-not-found

http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2010/06/02/source-not-found-debugging/

Comment: But what if your app only has one line, and it's a logging line?? Mine is giving the Source Not Found on Log.d("MyApp", "######## Test ######");, and yes I've imported android.util.Log and set debugging in the manifest.